# Nodejs modularized aws-sdk v3 size getting increased

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to reduce size of nodejs lambda bundle which uses aws-sdk.
This is the original lambda package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "lambdanodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.784.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "ioredis": "^4.19.2",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "redis-clustr": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Overall size is 57MB, 54 belongs to aws-sdk.

To reduce size I tried using specific client services (v3 sdk).
Followed : [https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/clients/client-secrets-manager/package.json](http://AWS%20SDK%20V3)

```
{
  "name": "lambdanodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.7.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager": "^3.7.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "ioredis": "^4.19.2",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "redis-clustr": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Now npm install results in even larger size around 190+MBs.
Also in node_modules I see lot of directories which were not there when using previous package.json install.
This v3 aws-sdk is supposed to be lighter.
Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share how you are bundling your artifact? Or do you just zip your source folder including the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @s.hesse I am zipping node_modules along with other files. These mentioned sizes are before zipping, but according to articles/blogs it should have lesser size, at least compared to aws-sdk it should be much lesser.

Comment: Ok.. Did you clean the `node_modules` folder before migrating to the new SDK? Maybe the old SDK folder is still there.

Comment: @s.hesse Yes I've removed package-lock.json and node_modules both.

Comment: Interesting.. so I just took your example `package.json` (with AWS SDK v3) and ran `npm install` and I have ~22MB of data in `node_modules`. Not sure what else you could do about it... Alternatively, try using something like `esbuild` to generate one artifact -> it'll bundle everything into one file and throw out all unnecessary code.

Comment: @s.hesse Yes, even my friend tried on windows machine and getting around same size ~20MB, on my machine however it is showing up 191MB bulky node_modules.

Comment: The @aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager library had huge size initially and I too faced the same issue, but as of now, after using the latest version the size of the node_modules has decreased considerably. Please upgrade the package version and try, it should be effective.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't push aws-sdk to the lambda function. If you want to use it in the local development environment install it globally.
- Lambda will provide all necessary SDK modules(v2 & v3) during runtime, just import them in the code.
- Don't bundle the aws-sdk in the zip.
- If your zip size is getting increased, use layers in lambda.
- Import the node_moudles to lambda layers.
- Then upload your code to lambda.

Comment: You mean I don't need package.json for aws modules, I can directly invoke import from code and those modules are available @ runtime?

Comment: Don't include aws-sdk or any version of aws-sdk in package.json and project node_modules

Comment: Assign s3 put object role to your lambda, write the code in lambda console for s3 put object and execute it. for testing purpose try this

Comment: Will try it out without any external package bundling.

Comment: It seems like the lambda nodejs environment comes with aws-sdk v2 pre-installed, but not v3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129993/does-aws-lambda-support-aws-sdk-v3-or-not

Comment: Yes, v2 pre-installed.

Comment: Installing a library globally in node is a really bad practice. Maybe consider something like yarn plug and play https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to V3 massively increased the size of my Node lambda bundles until I also upgraded the lambda runtime from NODEJS_14_X to NODEJS_18_X.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and in my case I solved it.

As @siva-sumanth said, you shouldn't include the SDK in your production code. In my case I'm using Serverless with serverless-bundle (a wrapper of serverless-webpack) and it was this package that excluded aws-sdk v2 by default bundling my code...unfortunately it doesn't in v3 because with module package you have to list all the packages you want to exclude (here the issue https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-bundle/issues/361)

Example:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-bundle

custom:
  bundle:
    forceExclude:
      - "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
      - "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb"
```